# Checking whether a mutable set contains an object with identical properties

Tags: objective-c

What I want to do, is create an `NSMutableSet`, the purpose of which would be to count how many pairs of unique data there are.

Basically, I have two mutable arrays; `xCoordinates` and `yCoordinates`, and a custom object called `XYPoint`. Each X coordinate and Y coordinate at coinciding indices combine to make a point on a cartesian plane. For example, at index 2, there may be in the `xCoordinates` array, the number 4 and in the `yCoordinates` array, the number 8, making the point (4, 8).

Now, to the crux of the question, what I want to do is check how many *unique* points are there. I was planning on using an `NSMutableSet` to do it. I.e:

```
for (int i = 0; i < [xCoordinates count]; i++) {

        XYPoint *newXY = [[XYPoint alloc] init];
        newXY.xCoordinate = [xCoordinates objectAtIndex:i];
        newXY.yCoordinate = [yCoordinates objectAtIndex:i];

        if ([distinct containsObject:newXY] == NO) {

            [distinct addObject:newXY];

        }

    }
```

Unfortunately, that doesn't work. Is there a way to say;

```
if (there isn't an object in the set with an identical X coordinate property and Y coordinate property){

    Add one to the set;

}
```

?

Comment: i guess set only allows unique values, it will not add duplicate values in it. for detail please [refer this doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableSet_Class/Reference/NSMutableSet.html)

Comment: Check this question/answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10586218/objective-c-nsmutableset-unique-object-property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Off the top of my head maybe some operation that yields a unique result would be enough for your particular case  (maybe not the most efficient solution though).

```
for (int i = 0; i < [xCoordinates count]; i++) {

    NSString *xStr = [[xCoordinates objectAtIndex:i] stringValue];
    NSString *yStr = [[yCoordinates objectAtIndex:i] stringValue];
    NSString *coordStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",xStr,yStr]; //edited
    if (![distinct containsObject:coordStr]) {
       [distinct addObject:coordStr];
    }
}
```

That should do I guess. Your solution was not working cause each time, a new object was created and wouldn't be equal. But for NSString like above thats not the case. Just a quick solution.

Comment: There's a hidden bug. Hint: consider points: 1, 11 and 11, 1.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe: Yup. Didn't think of that. Updated (Added a space between the %@s).

Answer (score 7):

`NSSet` uses `isEqual` when testing for membership.
`isEqual:` and `hash` are part of the [NSObject protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol).

If your XYPoint class derives from NSObject it inherits the default isEqual: implementation which is based on pointer equality. It compares the memory addresses to test if 2 objects are the same.
As your comparison criterion is *location*, you have to override `isEqual:` in your XYPoint class and return `YES` if the x/y coordinates of your 2 objects are the same.

Also have a look at the [Collections Programming Topics](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Collections/Collections.html). 
There is also a very detailed post about [equality and hashing by Mike Ash](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-06-18-implementing-equality-and-hashing.html).

**Update**
As JeremyP points out in the comments, you should always provide an implementation of `hash` when overriding `isEqual:`. Details are explained in the Mike Ash article above.
There is also a question discussing good hash functions for coordinates [here on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/682438/hash-function-providing-unique-uint-from-an-integer-coordinate-pair).

Comment: +1 for the detailed explanation and Mike Ash link.

Comment: This is a much better idea than converting the coordinates to strings.  But you also need to override `-hash` so that two objects that are equal have the same hash.

Comment: Good point - Thank you. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an enhanced version of Rakesh's proposal.

It doesn't suffer the subtleties of number-to-string conversion, plus it omits the redundant conditional.

It uses the common `NSValue` point wrapper instead of your custom class `XYPoint`.

```
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [xCoordinates count]; ++i) {
    CGPoint p = { [xCoordinates[i] floatValue], [yCoordinates[i] floatValue] };
   [distinct addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:p]];
}
```

Comment: Just a note. `valueWithCGPoint:` is only available in iOS. Anything similar in cocoa?

Comment: Btw this does not check for uniqueness.

Comment: @Rakesh OS X has `valueWithPoint:`. The generic way of putting CGPoints into an NSValue is described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2577651/104790

Comment: @Rakesh I thought it was clear that `distinct` is an `NSMutableSet` (that cares for the uniqueness). That's why I called the conditional redundant.

Comment: Yes. But when the CGPoints are created this way the equality between objects are not satisfied and the points with same co-ordinates are added to the `distinct` set. So the OP's problem still remains.

Comment: @Rakesh How do you come to this conclusion? Apple's documentation says: "For NSValue objects, the class, type, and contents are compared to determine equality".

Comment: Well when I tried out the code it added two identical(in values) objects. Maybe I did something wrong. Don't have access to a mac right now. Will let you know.

Comment: It was my mistake indeed. Had made a NSSet reference and had passed an NSArray object into it. Neat answer!! :)

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on [weichsel's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16162556/169346) which is the best here, the class implementation would look something like this:

```
@interface XYCoordinate : NSObject
-(id) initWithX: (NSNumber*) newX andY: (NSNumber*) newY;
@property (readonly, copy) NSNumber* x;
@property (readonly, copy) NDNumber* y;
@end

@implementation XYCoordinate

@synthesize x = _x;
@synthesize y = _y;

-(id) initWithX: (NSNumber*) newX andY: (NSNumber*) newY
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self != nil)
    {
         [self setX: newX];
         [self setY: newY];
    }
    return self;
}

-(BOOL) isEqual: (id) somethingElse
{
    BOOL ret = NO;
    if ([somethingElse isKindOfClass: [XYCoordinate class]])
    {
        ret = [[self x] isEqual: [somethingElse x]] && [[self y] isEqual: [somethingElse y]]
    }
    return ret;
}

-(NSUInteger) hash
{
     return [[self x] hash] + [[self y] hash];  // Probably a rubbish hash function, but it will do
}
@end
```