# avoid adding object to NSMutableArray if object already exists in the array

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I'm adding imageDataObject in imagesArray.

```
ImageData *imageDataObject = [[ImageData alloc]initWithImageId:[[imageListArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]imageId]
                                                     imageName:[[imageListArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] imageName]
                                                         image:[UIImage imageWithData:imageData]];
[imagesArray addObject:imageDataObject];
```

I want to avoid adding imageDataObject if it already exists in imagesArray.
imageDataObject is duplicate if imageId is already in the imagesArray object.
imageId is string value coming from URL.

I tried containsObject but it's not working.

I know there are similar questions but nothing works for me.

please help.

Comment: What makes two `imageDataObject` the same?  Just because two `imageDataObject` hold the same image or imageName doesn't make them the same (in terms of `containsObject`).  They just have the same contents.

Comment: Perhaps try using [`NSMutableOrderedSet`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSMutableOrderedSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html) instead

Comment: There is no practical way to tell that you have two distinct but identical images.  If you want to avoid dupes you need to keep track of the sources of the images and eliminate images with identical sources.

Comment: i just have to check imageid which is unique.

Comment: Using a `Set` would be your best option. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10586218/objective-c-nsmutableset-unique-object-property/10586479#10586479) may help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many ways, here are a selection:

1. It looks like `ImageData` is your own type. `NSArray`'s `containsObject:` determines if a matching object exists by calling `isEqual:`. So define `isEqual:` and `hash` (you must implement both) on `ImageData` which just compares for equality based on your `imageID` (whatever the type of that is).
2. If you cannot define `isEqual:` and `hash` as they already exist and are not based on `imagedID` then you can use `NSArray`'s `indexOfObjectPassingTest:` method. This takes a block which is called to test each element of the array in turn and returns the index of the first element which matches, or `NSNotFound` if no such element exists. Have the block test for your `imageID` and if the method returns `NSNotFound` you know there is no duplicate and the new `ImageData` should be added.
3. Store the `ImageData` objects in an `NSMutableDictionary` using your `imageID` as the key (if `imageID` is a primitive type then wrap it as an object to use it as a key, e.g. wrap `int` as an `NSNumber` - using modern syntax `5` is just `@5` as an `NSNumber`). You can easily test for key existence (a lookup returns `nil`), or just add new objects without checking as if there is a repeat the new value will just replace the old one.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement `-isEqual:` and `-hash` for your `ImageData` class. Once you do that correctly, then `-containsObject:` or a set (e.g. `NSMutableOrderedSet`) will be able to work correctly.

You don't explain what type an imageId is. If it's an object type, then you can piggy-back on its definition of equality. If it's an integer type, you can either do something simple like using the integer value as the hash, or you can implement it in terms of `NSNumber`s equality and hash implementations.